# Curl Errors While Pulling from Twitter

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I'm trying to pull some data from twitter via PHP.  I'm using the tmhOAuth plugin, which can be found here. https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/

I wrote my code based off the example file "streaming.php", which can also be found on the above github page.  Here is my code:

```
    require 'tmhOAuth.php';

    $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
            'consumer_key' => 'xxxhiddenxxx',
            'consumer_secret' => 'xxxhiddenxxx',
            'user_token' => 'xxxhiddenxxx',
            'user_secret' => 'xxxhiddenxxx'
    ));

    $method = 'http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json';

    $params = array(
            'follow' => '1307392917',
            'count'  => '5'
    );
    $tmhOAuth->streaming_request('POST', $method, $params, 'my_streaming_callback');
    $tmhOAuth->pr($tmhOAuth);
```

That was not printing out any of the twitter data I wanted to pull, and was only showing the debug information that the pr() command writes.

While trying to debug why I wasn't getting any data, I went in and added a line to tmhOAuth.php so that I could see what error cURL was giving.  I did this by using

```
 echo curl_error($C);
```

The error that cURL outputed was :

> transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

I've done some research on that error, but I can't find anything that helps.  There were a couple things that I found regarding content-length, but when I dug into the code I saw that the author of tmhOAuth had already addressed those issues (and commenting out his fixes didn't help).

Any help?

**Update 1**  Here is the response info gathered using curl_getinfo:

```
//Removed - an updated version is below
```

**Update 2**  Thanks to the comments below I realized that twitter was sending me data with transfer-encoding: chunked.  I put this line into tmhOAuth.php to force out chunked data:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
```

That worked, somewhat.  I'm no longer getting any cURL errors, but my WRITEFUNCTION callback is still never getting called - so I'm never getting any actual data.  Here's the output of my cURL object again:

```
    [response] => Array
        (
            [content-length] => 0
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
                    [server] => Jetty(6.1.25)
                )

            [code] => 416
            [response] => 1
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json
                    [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
                    [http_code] => 416
                    [header_size] => 116
                    [request_size] => 532
                    [filetime] => -1
                    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
                    [redirect_count] => 0
                    [total_time] => 0.118553
                    [namelookup_time] => 0.043927
                    [connect_time] => 0.070477
                    [pretransfer_time] => 0.07049
                    [size_upload] => 25
                    [size_download] => 0
                    [speed_download] => 0
                    [speed_upload] => 210
                    [download_content_length] => -1
                    [upload_content_length] => -1
                    [starttransfer_time] => 0.118384
                    [redirect_time] => 0
                    [request_header] => POST /1/statuses/filter.json HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: themattharris' HTTP Client
Host: stream.twitter.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxhiddenxxx", oauth_nonce="xxxhidden", oauth_signature="xxxhidden", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1308226585", oauth_token="xxxhiddenxxx", oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


                )

        )

)
```

**Update 3:**  Couple things I've figured out so far...  I removed the 'count' parameters from my POST request, and now the page seems to take forever.  I figured this meant it was just downloading tons and tons of data, so I put a break into the streaming callback function, setup so that it kills the page after 5 loops.

I did this, and let it sit for quite awhile.  After about 5 minutes, the page finished loading, and showed me what data I had gathered.  It looked like I had gotten no data each time it ran through - only an end of line character.  So, it's taking a minute for every piece of data I am downloading, and even then the only data that shows is an end of line character.  Weird?  Is this a twitter issue or a cURL issue?

Comment: Does the response header you get use Content-Length or is it using chunked Transfer-Encoding?  That may provide a hint.

Comment: Not sure how to check, so I just posted all of the response info I was able to find.

Comment: It looks to be like it is chunked (see content-length and transfer_encoding near the top of your update).  I have seen cases where a buggy server chunked reply can cause this problem, so it is a shot that maybe this is an issue.  You would need a network trace or a curl packet debug dump to try and confirm it though.  This is just a guess, I would wait to see if you get any other ideas first before going down this path.

Comment: Oh!  I didn't even see that transfer-encoding line - that makes me feel stupid.  I haven't gotten any other answers, but have heard this chunk thing on different posts before..  How do I go about fixing my error, then?

Comment: Your request is failing with 416 - Requested Range Not Satisfiable
A server usually returns a response with 416-status code if a request included a Range request-header field, and none of the range-specifier values in this field overlap the current extent of the selected resource, and the request did not include an If-Range request-header field. For example if the resource is an image file and has 1000 bytes, and the Range requested is 500-1500, then it cannot be satisfied. [link](http://www.websitepulse.com/kb/4xx_HTTP_status_codes.html)

Comment: It sounds like you are not using the Streaming API for its intended purpose. Streams should only be opened by persistant daemons running in the background, not by scripts that are rendering content to the browser. A stream connection should remain open and dump the data to a database/log/cache where it can get processed and pulled for display for users. If you want to make a request to the API to get specific data for each page request use the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the token api but never got something good, so this is the script I found [here](http://blog.loicg.net/developpement-web/lire-twitter-stream-php-curl/) :

```
<?php
/**
 * API Streaming for Twitter.
 *
 * @author  Loïc Gerbaud <gerbaudloic@gmail.com>
 * @version 0.1 "itjustworks"
 */

define('TWITTER_LOGIN','login'); //login twitter
define('TWITTER_PASSWORD','myp4ssw0rd');    //password twitter
$sTrackingList = 504443371;//read my account but could be keywords

// ?
while(1){
 echo 'Connexion ';
 read_the_stream($sTrackingList);
 echo 'Deconnexion ';
}

/**read the stream
 *
 */
function read_the_stream($sTrackingList){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json');
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,TWITTER_LOGIN.':'.TWITTER_PASSWORD);//Le couple login:password
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Twitter-Client: ItsMe','X-Twitter-Client-Version: 0.1','X-Twitter-Client-URL: http://blog.loicg.net/'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"follow=".$sTrackingList);//read the doc for your request
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'write_callback');//function callback

 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
}

/** a demo with a writting log or put in MySQL
 */


 function write_callback($ch, $data) {
 if(strlen($data)>2){
 $oData = json_decode($data);
 if(isset($oData->text)){
 file_put_contents('log',$oData->text."\n",FILE_APPEND);
 }
 }
 return strlen($data);
} 
?>
```

run this script in your browser (you can close it after), update your twitter account and check the .log

Answer (score 0):

> After about 5 minutes, the page finished loading

Are you running streaming.php in the browser? If so, you have to run it via ssl, otherwise it doesn't work. I have a server chron job pointing to the file but you can do it also with the terminal:

```
 php /path/to/here/streaming.php
```

For view the data you are getting, you can store it into a database or log:

```
function my_streaming_callback($data, $length, $metrics) {  
    $ddf = fopen('/twitter/mydata.log','a');
    fwrite($ddf,$data);
    fclose($ddf);
}
```